# Chrome browser freezes after uploading/downloading files

Tags: release-freya, google-chrome

This problem happens consistently. If I try to download a document from a web page, it does the download but, the browser freezes and I have to restart it. Same thing happens when I upload a picture. It uploads it but Chrome freezes. I have no problems with either Firefox or Opera browsers. Your help to solve this is appreciated.
My OS version is elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (64-bit) and Chrome version is:Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround to solve this problem is found on:
[Issue 716892](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=716892#c5)

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem from browser side.. 
So browser won't work properly if the upload size or download size is great.

You can use Firefox or chromium browser for freeze free operations.

There is no other solutions! 
May be the future update of chrome will not freeze.